# How To Generate notification on Activity

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application in which I want to generate alarm or sound on (activity B) when the user hits a button on (activity A).

Till now I'm thinking this can be done by firebase like when the new data arrives in the database from (activity A) Then (activity B) will load the data and start making sound/alarm.

How can implementation of this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can save the data of activity A's button click in **sharedprefrences**
([https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-preferences-in-android-with-examples/#:~:text=Shared%20Preferences%20is%20the%20way,app%20on%20the%20device%20storage.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-preferences-in-android-with-examples/#:%7E:text=Shared%20Preferences%20is%20the%20way,app%20on%20the%20device%20storage.))
and when moves to activity B, you can use that data in onStart method or access it from Broadcast receiver to show you alarm manager in activity B.
Hope it might help you in understanding.

Comment: but i want to do all this on multiple devices